# Add tag to cartridge admin panel

Tags: python, django, cartridge

I want to add one new field 'tag' in my Product class. I added that field and now I want to add that tag manually from cartridge admin panel.

So, to do that I am importing one admin class in my settings.py,

```
from cartridge.shop.admin import ProductAdmin
```

When I am importing above class, I am getting error on terminal,

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.

I wants to add that "tag" field in ProductAdmin class like below,but before I write below code in my project I am getting that "SECRET_KEY" error on import,

```
ProductAdmin.list_display.append("tag")
```

Comment: Set the `SECRET_KEY` in your settings to a long random secret string.

Comment: I already have a SECRET_KEY in my settings.py

Comment: The you have a circular import masking the value. Basically you should prevent all imports there. BTW `append()` returns `None` and `list_display` will become `None`.

Comment: I edited the code about append().  Now is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

`ProductAdmin` looks like it requires the secret key setting which it is unable to get since it is loaded before settings, so you cannot include this in settings (nor can I think of a reason you'd need to)

Whatever it is you're trying to do, you need to do it elsewhere.

Comment: So, where can I import and write code about this? I mean in which file so that it is executed when I run the server.

Comment: @AkashWankhede - I don't know enough about cartridge, but if its anything like django admin pages, you define them in the `admin.py` files

Comment: Okay.  Thanks for suggestion.